# old postgres DB, serving confluence wiki behind IIS. From time to time all tables in DB happen to be deleted

Tags: postgresql, security, iis, confluence, server-side-attacks

We have an old Postgres DB, serving confluence wiki behind IIS. From time to time, all tables in DB happen to be deleted.

Can anybody give me a clue to help me understand the problem?
seems to be it can be a security problem.

I found nothing in IIS logs (did expect an injection attack).
Nothing special found in windows events list (application + security)

the only clear point - in postgres db logs we see that the operation was performed (before, a call to get all tables available is also visible).

all software is about 10 years old, except Windows Server 2022.

1. Postgres version 9.2
2. some entries in log:
   2023-12-20 12:01:02 PST ERROR:  table "contentlock" does not exist
   2023-12-20 12:01:02 PST STATEMENT:  drop table CONTENTLOCK
   2023-12-20 12:01:02 PST ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
   2023-12-20 12:01:02 PST STATEMENT:  SELECT NULL AS TABLE_CAT, n.nspname AS TABLE_SCHEM, c.relname AS TABLE_NAME,  CASE n.nspname ~ '^pg_' OR n.nspname = 'information_schema'  WHEN true THEN CASE  WHEN n.nspname = 'pg_catalog' OR n.nspname = 'information_schema' THEN CASE c.relkind   WHEN 'r' THEN 'SYSTEM TABLE'   WHEN 'v' THEN 'SYSTEM VIEW'   WHEN 'i' THEN 'SYSTEM INDEX'   ELSE NULL   END  WHEN n.nspname = 'pg_toast' THEN CASE c.relkind   WHEN 'r' THEN 'SYSTEM TOAST TABLE'   WHEN 'i' THEN 'SYSTEM TOAST INDEX'   ELSE NULL   END  ELSE CASE c.relkind   WHEN 'r' THEN 'TEMPORARY TABLE'   WHEN 'i' THEN 'TEMPORARY INDEX'   WHEN 'S' THEN 'TEMPORARY SEQUENCE'   WHEN 'v' THEN 'TEMPORARY VIEW'   ELSE NULL   END  END  WHEN false THEN CASE c.relkind  WHEN 'r' THEN 'TABLE'  WHEN 'i' THEN 'INDEX'  WHEN 'S' THEN 'SEQUENCE'  WHEN 'v' THEN 'VIEW'  WHEN 'c' THEN 'TYPE'  WHEN 'f' THEN 'FOREIGN TABLE'  ELSE NULL  END  ELSE NULL  END  AS TABLE_TYPE, d.description AS REMARKS  FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n, pg_catalog.pg_class c  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_description d ON (c.oid = d.objoid AND d.objsubid = 0)  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class dc ON (d.classoid=dc.oid AND dc.relname='pg_class')  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace dn ON (dn.oid=dc.relnamespace AND dn.nspname='pg_catalog')  WHERE c.relnamespace = n.oid  AND c.relname LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT' AND (false  OR ( c.relkind = 'r' AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_' AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema' ) )  ORDER BY TABLE_TYPE,TABLE_SCHEM,TABLE_NAME
   2023-12-20 12:01:06 PST ERROR:  relation "cwd_app_dir_group_mapping" does not exist
   2023-12-20 12:01:06 PST STATEMENT:  alter table cwd_app_dir_group_mapping drop constraint fk_app_dir_group_app

Comment: Add answers to following as text update to question text. 1) Postgres version? Though anything 10+ old is past EOL. 2) What is the command you see issued in the logs? 3)You should look at what is available for `log_line_prefix` here [What to log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT) for your version of Postgres and then use to add more information to log prefix.

Comment: Change all passwords and lock down access to the database. Like you said, you’re most likely hacked

Comment: thank you for suggestions, will try to get more detailed log

Answer (score 1):

After changing all passwords...

Assuming your web software uses a library or ORM to make database queries, you have one single place where you can intercept all queries. So you need to put some code in there to detect the queries done by this hacker, and when they are detected, first don't do the query, and second log absolutely everything you can. You should also configure IIS for better logging. Then perhaps you can use that information to find the vulnerability in your code and patch it.

If your code is sprayed with "pg_query(...)" in random places then you probably have  SQL injection somewhere, since quoting parameters "by hand" is a recipe for bugs.

That said it may not be a SQL injection, it could also be a remote code execution, remote shell, etc.

If you're using any outdated web app (php forum or whatever) then it needs to be patched and updated.

Assuming your IIS server uses a database user "webuser" to connect to the database.

Create a new database user, say "user2" who will have all permissions. The idea is to restrict webuser as much as possible. The goal is to prevent the bad stuff from happening, while also raising an error so you can trace it and patch the hole. These are not permanent fixes, but ways to get more information.

First, if your app doesn't need to list tables or do anything with information_schema, just revoke all privileges on it and the [system tables](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/postgresql-revoking-permissions-from-pg_catalog-tables/) so webuser can't list tables.

Webuser is probably the owner of the tables, which means it can do anything to them including DROP. In order to prevent that, you can grant ownership of all tables to user2, and revoke ownership of everything (database, table, etc) from webuser. Then selectively grant only the needed [privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) to webuser (ie, select, update, delete).

Comment: thank you very much for this description